# onScroll scrollTo behavior smooth in Chrome

Tags: javascript, scroll

can someone please explain why window.scrollTo does not work properly within a window.onscroll event in Chrome? The example in fiddle is with element.scrollIntoView but the behaviour is the same. The smooth scrolling is very very slow.

HTML

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom">
```

CSS

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0
} 

body {
background-image: radial-gradient(#166664 0%, #252233 80%);
}

#top {
height: 100vh;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

#bottom {
height: 1800px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

JS

```
 window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {

    var bottomel = document.getElementById("bottom");
    var newscroll = window.pageYOffset;

    if (newscroll > 0) {
        bottomel.scrollIntoView({
            block: "start",
            behavior: "smooth"
        });
    } 
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3doc8ap5/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove listener after scroll starts to avoid multiple execution:

```
function onScroll(event) {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

  var bottomel = document.getElementById("bottom");
  var newscroll = window.pageYOffset;

  if (newscroll > 0) {
    bottomel.scrollIntoView({
      block: "start",
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }

  event.preventDefault();
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
```